# Identify Operation on the basis of xml content posted in WCF Service without including operation name in Url

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

How to identify operation from xml content posted to WCF Service Url?
Suppose WCF Service Url is http://single.mat.nn.com and client dont want to include operation name in Url.
Problem is to identify operation on the basis of xml content posted .

I am not able to find any solution for this problem. Is it feasible to do configuration in WCF Service that can identify operation method on the basis of xml content posted to WCF Service URL.

Answer (score 0):

One of the scenarios possible in [Extending Dispatchers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/extending-dispatchers) is:

> Custom Operation Dispatching. Users can implement dispatching on something other than action – for example, on the body element, or on a custom message property. This can be done using the IDispatchOperationSelector interface.

Implmenting [IDispatchOperationSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchoperationselector?view=netframework-4.8) will give you access to the incoming message to parse and decide which method you want to forward the request to.

Comment: I want to acheive Dispatch by Body Element . Detect the operation name from root element of xml posted. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP web service based on the corresponding method of the SOAPAction field request in the HTTP request. See the screenshot below.
[image]
The SOAPAction field and the method section in the request body can view the operation name of the specific request. If you want to recognize this value, we can intercept the SOAP message through the following two interfaces and get the value of the field.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-messages-on-the-client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.8
these two interfaces could capture the SOAP message during the communication. We could retrieve the field value and modify it.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Is it feasible to call OperationContract methods without including name in Url . As user is posting response xml to Url http://simpleinterface.at.com/service.svc?wsdl . Getting 400 bad request error . User dont want to include operation name in url . He wants to post xml to single url

Comment: I have a little confused about your question. the client invocation to the service doesn't include the operation name in URL, only the service base address. http://10.157.13.69:8864/service1.svc
Only the Restful style service include the operation name and Http-verb.
in the SOAP web service, the invocation on the client-side generally is completed by the client proxy class.
ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient();
            var result = client.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);